# Parse this string in Java

Tags: java, string, parsing

i'm new to Java . How can i obtain right values of each line (second value of the dash separated pair)

> Autorul-Stefan
>
> DenumireaCartii-Popovici
>
> CuloareaCartii-Verde
>
> GenulCartii-Religie
>
> Limba-Rusa

**SOLVED :**

```
 String line = "Autorul-Stefan";
    String [] fields = line.split("-");
    fields[0] == "Autorul"
    fields[1] == "stefan"
```

Comment: Do you mean "the second value of the dash separated pair"?

Comment: How can we know which is the 'right value' from your point of view ? :)

Comment: yes ,the second value of the dash separated pair

Comment: @devXcode, if the problem is solved, please accept the answer that solved it instead of adding "(SOLVED)" in the title of your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String line = "Autorul-Stefan";
String [] fields = line.split("-");
// fields[0] == "Autorul"
// fields[1] == "stefan"
```

Answer (score 4):

use [String.split()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String right = str.split("-")[1];
```

where `str` contains your String object

Answer (score 2):

```
  String strings = "Autorul-Stefan";
  String[] tempo;


  tempo = strings.split("-");
    System.out.println(tempo[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` function in `Strings`:

```
String rightValue = line.split("-")[1];
```

Where `line` is the each line of your text (like "Autorul-Stefan") and `rightValue` is the text to the right of the dash (like "Stefan").

You use `[1]` to get the second element of the split text (`split` separates the given `String` into an array using the given character (here `"-"`) as a divider) So in this example, the first element of the array is the text to the left of the dash and the second element is the text to the right of the dash.